# Group sum and count with two unique columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to groupby two column, sum and take the count of these values.

**Data**

```
source  ex  pw  role    date
aa          10  hello   q222
aa          10  hello   q222
        bb  15  ok      q422
        bb  5   no      q422
        bb  1   sure    q422
        bb  4   yes     q422
```

**Desired**

```
source  ex  pw  count   date
aa          20  2       q222
        bb  25  4       q422
```

**Doing**

```
#df.groupby(['source','date'])['pw'].agg(['count','sum'])
df.groupby(['ex','date'])['pw'].agg(['count','sum'])
```

However, with this,  I have to now perform a concatenation to merge the two outputs. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby()` with `dropna=False` + `rename()`:

```
out=(df.groupby(['source','ex','date'],dropna=False)['pw'].agg(['count','sum'])
      .reset_index().rename(columns={'sum':'pw'}))
```

OR

`groupby()` with `dropna=False` and aggregration with named tuples:

```
out=(df.groupby(['source','ex'],dropna=False)
       .agg(pw=('pw','sum'),count=('pw','count'),date=('date','first'))
       .reset_index())
```

output of `out`:

```
    source  ex      date    count   pw
0   aa      NaN     q222    2       20
1   NaN     bb      q422    4       25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby` with new key create with `fillna`

```
out = df.groupby([df.source.fillna(df.ex),df.date]).agg({'source':'first',
                                                   'ex':'first',
                                                   'pw':'sum',
                                                   'role':'count',
                                                   'date':'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[489]: 
  source    ex  pw  role  date
0     aa  None  20     2  q222
1   None    bb  25     4  q422
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
>>> df.fillna('').groupby(['source','ex','date']).agg({'pw': [sum, 'count']})
                pw      
               sum count
source ex date          
       bb q422  25     4
aa        q222  20     2
```